# Underscore not visible in Java numbers

Tags: java

The underscore is not visible in integer data types:

```
int intHex = 0x0041;
System.out.println("intHex: " + intHex);
int intBinary = 0b01000001;
System.out.println("intBinary: " + intBinary);
int intUnderscore = 1_23_456;
System.out.println("intUnderscore: " + intUnderscore);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please include code as code, not as a screenshot.

Comment: The underscore is not part of the data. It is a syntax feature that makes numeric constants more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect that

```java
int intUnderscore = 1_23_456;
System.out.println("intUnderscore: " + intUnderscore);
```

prints

```
intUnderscore: 1_23_456
```

you misunderstod the purpose of the underscore. It is just syntactic sugare meant to make source code easier to read.